# PyGauge does not honor style=GA_VERTICAL

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to use a vertical gauge using PyGauge in wx.Python and the bar paints horizontally, not vertically.  When using regular wx.Gauge, style=GA_VERTICAL works as expected, but when I switch to PyGauge in wx.lib.agw.pygauge, the bar paints from the side.

from wx.lib.agw.pygauge import PyGauge

self.pita = PyGauge(self.parent_pane, wx.ID_ANY, 100, style=wx.GA_VERTICAL)

trying various size=(100,25) parameters did not change anything.

python 2.7, wxPython 2.8.12.1

Answer (score 0):

See [Github mirror for wxPython Phoenix, pygauge.py](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/wx/lib/agw/pygauge.py#L10), Line 10:

```
# TODO List
# ...
# 2. Vertical bar
# ...
```

You will have to convince the author to implement it...

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction.  I modified the last else clause to look for the GA_VERTICAL flag:`

                r = copy.copy(rect)
                if self.WindowStyle & wx.GA_VERTICAL:
                    h = rect.height * (float(self._valueSorted[i]) / self._range)
                    r.height = h
                else:
                    w = rect.width * (float(self._valueSorted[i]) / self._range)
                    r.width = w 
`